# Sending textarea value to a redux action creator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following component:

```
const myComponent = ({handleClick, default = ''}) => (
  <div>
    <textarea name="myTextArea" defaultValue={default}></textarea>
    <button onClick={(myTextArea) => handleClick(myTextArea})}>Done</button>
  </div>
)
```

Dispatch mapping:

```
 const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   return {
      handleClick: (myTextArea) => {
         console.log(myTextArea); // This is syntheticMouseEvent
      }
    }
  }
```

`myTextArea` is always of type `syntheticMouseEvent`

Am I doing something wrong? Where is my value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the event for the button click, which has nothing to do with the text area.  There's a couple different ways you can handle things.  One is to implement the "controlled inputs" pattern and keep the current value of the text area in state (either Redux state or component state).  Another is to save a "ref" to the text area, and retrieve its value from the real DOM element when the button is clicked.

I have links to a number of articles on [React and Forms](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/react-forms.md) as part of my React/Redux links list, which explain what the "controlled input" pattern is and how you can use it.